# Bootstrapping A Records for a DNS Server

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, a-record, glue-record, nsd

My problem is this.

Dissatisfied with the existing free DNS nameserver solutions, I decided to make my own nameservers for my websites. I'm using NSD on Debian, and it's working great. I can request a record from the server with DIG and get the correct response and all that jazz.

However, there's a catch that I can't figure out how to circumvent. In order to give my nameservers to my domain registrar, they need A records. (ns1.example.com etc.)

Here's the issue: Since I'm having these servers handle the DNS for all of my domains, I'm not sure how to create A records for the servers themselves. If I create the ns1, ns2 records inside my own server, my registrar won't be able to look them up. But in order to create those records externally so I can point a registrar to my servers, I need to register those A records with an external source, right?

How can I bootstrap the A records for my nameservers so my registrar can see them long enough to plug in? Or am I misunderstanding the problem entirely?

I hope that made a bit of sense.

Answer (score 5):

What you need is some [glue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records) ([1](http://faq.domainmonster.com/dns/glue_record/)).

Basically what you do is tell your both the name and IP address for your servers.  They will make A records for your servers in the parent zone.

So if you happened to be talking about `example.org`, then the .org servers would have a set of records like this to delegate to you.

```
ns1.example.org. in a 192.0.2.10
ns2.example.org. in a 192.0.2.11
example.org. in ns ns1.example.org.
example.org. in ns ns2.example.org.
```

Comment: As of January 3rd 2012, my registrar still does not support glue. However, is it possible to simply use a third party DNS provider just to publish the A records to my nameservers?

Comment: What registrar is that?  I can't imagine how any valid registrar would be able to get away with that.

Comment: There was a discussion about it on DynaDot's forums, but I may have misunderstood.  I'll just contact them directly.

Comment: See: http://www.dynadot.com/community/help/question.html?aid=87